# How to convert Java8 Lambda expression into corresponding Java7 code

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have been wondering how to convert the below lambda expression (which is Java8's biggest language feature) into corresponding Java 7

```
final JmsBolt jmsBolt = new JmsBolt();
jmsBolt.setJmsMessageProducer((session, input) -> {
        final String json = "{\"stateCode\":\"" + input.getString(0) + "\", \"sentiment\":" + input.getInteger(1) + "}";
        return session.createTextMessage(json);
```

This is JmsBolt Class:

```
public class JmsBolt extends BaseRichBolt {

 ...
 public void setJmsMessageProducer(JmsMessageProducer producer){
    this.producer = producer;
 } 
 ...
}
```

And here is the JmsMessageProducer functional interface:

```
public interface JmsMessageProducer extends Serializable{

public Message toMessage(Session session, Tuple input) throws JMSException;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to create anonymous classes?

Comment: Try to provide compiling code, it is impossible to help if we can't compile the code you're providing as test.

Answer (score 2):

I think an anonymous class will help you:

```
jmsBolt.setJmsMessageProducer(new JmsMessageProducer() {

    @Override
    public Message toMessage(Session session, Tuple input) {
        ...
    }

});
```

Comment: Ahh, I did not think of it, now it feels easy :) , thank you

Comment: Yes you are right. I'd give you multiple up votes to compensate if I could. The lambda expression is logically nothing more than syntactic sugar for an anonymous class. Physically, it generates different bytecode, but that only because they *can* do it by not creating a new class, an option that doesn't exist in Java 7.

Comment: @Andreas: actually, [*can* do the same in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleProxies.html#asInterfaceInstance(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle)), but you not with such a concise syntax and you have to give up compile-time checks when Generics is involved…